# Having problems understanding $_GET forms in php

Tags: php, mysql, get

I am having problem with `$_GET` array. More precisely I'm retrieving data from mysql database and writing as output like this;

```
while ($reg_pins = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><span class='tmp_id'>" . $reg_pins['tmp_id'] . ")</span></td>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "<td><span class='tmp_id'>" . $reg_pins['rights'] . "</span></td>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "<td><span class='tmp_id'>" . $reg_pins['reg_pin'] . "</span></td>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "<td><a class='del_a' href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?delete=" . $reg_pins['tmp_id'] . "' >Delete&nbsp;Key</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

(I didn't write whole connection and other statements what is needed for retrieving data from database)

This is work perfectly, but I want to delete some of this data, so I can not write code to delete it.

**I am interested in how I can manipulate with this situation (with `$_GET` method) to achieve my goal?**

Comment: Do **NOT** use GET requests to delete data on the server. One web spider in your site and your site is GONE: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Spider_of_Doom.aspx

Comment: $_GET['delete'] will be set to the tmp_id of the clicked item. Write a query that uses this id to delete that value. Make sure you protect against SQL injection. Ideally with [MySQLi's bind-param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) - yes, and the above. One would assume this is a logged in user with the correct permissions and CSRF protections.

Comment: thanks for advice, but in this situation is only example, because in general i want to understand how to write code with php which does something after clicking on <a href="/somethig?some=">Link</a> (I have a basic understanding in web programing but i can not guess how to do that) for example from HTML FORMS <form name="some"><input type="text" name="x"><input type="submit" name="go"></form> i write so <?php if (isset($_POST['go'])){echo $_POST['x'];} ?> and works nice. But when i do no want to use HTML FORM, but also use single <a href="/link"></a> how can i connect it to php ?

Comment: It would just be `<a href="/link?param1=data1&param2=data2">Link name</a>` then on the php side it would be `$data1 = (isset($_GET['param1']))?$_GET['param1']:''; $data2 = (isset($_GET['param2']))?$_GET['param2']:'';` Then any passing data from param1 and 2 will be stored in data1 and 2 respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but apparently you're asking how to send information to a php script when the user clicks on a link.

If that's your question, then you have to use url parameters. They are codified as follows:

```
http://yoururl.com?param_name=value&param_name2=value2
```

And so on and so on...
What you're doing is adding parameters after the "?" and you separate them with the "&" sign. Values can have anything you want (numbers, strings, etc).

On your php script, you catch the values as follows:

```
$value1 = $_GET['param_name'];
$value2 = $_GET['param_name2'];
```

Does that help you? Let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$reg_pins['tmp_id'] = 40;
echo "<td>
<a class='del_a' href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?delete=".$reg_pins
['tmp_id'].">Delete</a></td>";
```

you can get

```
$reg_pins ['tmp_id'] value by $tmp_id = $_GET['delete']
```

you can also user jquery to get id by passing extra attr id like href in a tag and remove ? delete from href.